# Remote db connection in Flask python

Tags: python, database, flask, guidewire

Hi i need to read policy details from Guidewire Software to my Flask application by passing policy number to it.
how can I set up it ?

Comment: What is Guidewire Software? If it is a third party API/app contact with their customer service.

Answer (score 1):

You should expose a web service (using SOAP or REST) in your Guidewire application.

Once the web service is established, it should work in the following way:

1. Python application passes a policy number to Guidewire
2. Guidewire retrieves a policy from your database
3. Guidewire sends a response back (policy details)
4. Flask receives it

If you don't know how to expose a web service in Guidewire, you should be able to find all necessary information in Guidewire's documentation.